# Flask Global Variable per session other than Session Object

Tags: ajax, session, flask

I am using AJAX calls to get data from the server every 60 seconds. I need to have a variable at the server, which  I can modify up on each AJAX call.

1. I can't use the Session variable as AJAX calls can't modify the session.
2. I can't use `g` as it's per request variable.
3. I can use database to store the related data. But clean up is difficult upon a session expiry (which is currently 15 minutes.)

So what should I use for the above purpose? The variable should be modifiable through AJAX calls and should be deleted along with the session.

Comment: Why can't Ajax calls modify the session?

Comment: I was trying to change, but after changing also, the initial value persists. Then I came across with this question and answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316224/flask-session-variable-does-not-update-when-using-ajax